# Creating bucket in Google Cloud Storage in custom location

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-python

I would like to create a bucket in GCS based in Europe using the python client.

```
from google.cloud import storage
```

## Instantiates a client

```
storage_client = storage.Client()
```

## The name for the new bucket

```
bucket_name = 'my-new-bucket'
```

## Creates the new bucket

```
bucket = storage_client.create_bucket(bucket_name)

print('Bucket {} created.'.format(bucket.name))
```

This creates the bucket multiregional in the US. How can I change this to Europe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `create_bucket` method is limited. For more parameters, you'd create a bucket resource and invoke its `create()` method, like so:

```
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.bucket('bucket-name')
bucket.create(location='EU')
```

Bucket.create has a few other properties and is documented: https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/buckets.html#google.cloud.storage.bucket.Bucket.create

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this:

```py
def create_bucket(bucket_name):
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.create_bucket(bucket_name, location='EUROPE-WEST1')
    print("Bucket {} created".format(bucket.name))
```